# Access excel worksheet rows with passcode online

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel file which has more than 100 rows for each student in my class. Each row has the current points of a certain student and is named with his firstname_lastname. I wonder how I can put online and allow every student to only access his row using a passcode or something. Any ideas please?

Comment: Excel isn't the best tool for that. You can solve it with VBA, but it's rather complicated and it's very easy to break password protection of VBA modules. What other tools do you have access to? I think best solution would be if you can upload that to a sharepoint site where you can grant access at record (row) level. Other workaround can be mail merge in Word where you can generate (and even send in e-mail) documents at student level.

Comment: @MátéJuhász could you please show me how this can be done on sharepoint?

Comment: It's called audience targeting in sharepoint, you can find more information on it here (https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Introduction-to-targeting-content-on-a-SharePoint-site-to-specific-audiences-3009b54d-c157-4d85-ae1f-18a974b63524) and here (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261958%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and also a lot of information is available online